# what training method algorithm is used by tesseract

Tags: algorithm, methods, tesseract, training-data

I want to know what training method algorithm used by tesseract 3.03/3.04/3.05, i have searched to [github](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract), but I couldn't find a detailed documentation and I don't feel browsing the source code.

Answer (score 0):

It's under Wiki pages, specifically:

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Training-Tesseract

Comment: it's only mentioned that for 4.0 only train with the LSTM method. I need method for lower version